# big question about generics in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, generics

Before I start I want you to know that I am Latino and I am not very good at English so I had to use google to translate my question. I hope you can help me.

I am learning typescript and I have just entered the topic of generics, everything was fine but I found an example that I cannot understand. In the following image, how is it that typescript knows that the generic parameters of the "compare" function are <number, string>?

```
 class Pair<K, V> {
    constructor(public key: K, public value: V) {}
}

function compare <K,V> (pair1: Pair<K,V>, pair2: Pair<K,V>): void {    
    console.log(pair1, pair2);
}

let p1 = new Pair(1, "Apple");
let p2 = new Pair(1, "Orange");

compare(p1, p2);
```

Supposedly these types are inferred from the arguments that are sent therefore calling the function should look like this.

```
compare<Pair<number, string>, Pair<number, string>>();
```

I can't understand it. Another thing that I noticed is that it seems that it takes the types of the first argument because if the second object has different types it will show me an error like in this image

```
class Pair<K, V> {
    constructor(public key: K, public value: V) {}
}

function compare <K,V> (pair1: Pair<K,V>, pair2: Pair<K,V>): void {    
    console.log(pair1, pair2);
}

let p1 = new Pair(1, "Apple");
let p2 = new Pair('dani', "Orange");

compare(p1, p2); //error in second argument
```

I hope you can help me. I wish you all an excellent day.

Comment: Long story short: it's compiler magic. The compiler sees the definition of pair, which is generic and has two type variables `K` and `V`. When you create a new pair, you assign those type variables, either explicitly or implicitly. Compare is defined as taking two pairs, and therefore should define type variables as well. The key to generics is this: the types themselves are variable.

Comment: For the latter question, `K` and `V` just mean that they are two different types that you are comparing. They can be `any type` but they `cannot` be the `same type`. When you create a new `Pair` and pass in two values which are of the same type i.e. two strings it throws an error. In this case `K` is of type `string` so no issue there, but `V` is also of type `string` so it is an issue, it has to be a different type as specified in the function `compare`.